# How to get value of an array inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

Example:

```
foreach ($AllowAttributes as $attribute) {

    $medida_cart = $attribute['options'];
    print_r($medida_cart);
}
```

Displays on the screen Array ( [22] => 5.40 x 2.10 )

I want this value 5.40 x 2.10 without having to use the index

```
$medida_cart = $attribute['options'][22];
```

The index 22 will be changed forever, and always will have only one value, example:

```
Array ([random] => data I need)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `current()` or `reset()`:

```
$medida_cart = reset($attribute['options']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$medida_cart = array_values($attribute['options'])[0];
```

This will make the associative array into a sequential array and get the first and only value.

**[array_values() DOCUMENTATION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)**